# opt_fields not working with Asana API but url works in the Asana explorer

Tags: ruby, asana

I'm using Ruby starting from the "hello world" example.  Hello world works find.  I'm trying to get this GET to work:

```
GET /projects/192372431230306/tasks?opt_fields=id,assignee,due_on,name,notes&limit=10&completed_since=now
```

It works exactly as expected in the Asana API explorer.

I'm using the same URI in my code:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/192372431230306/tasks?opt_fields=id,assignee,due_on,name,notes&limit=10&completed_since=now")
```

It still returns ID and Name correctly, but it's not what I want.

I can't see why it works in the explorer but not in the GET request.  I am using the personal token and the explorer uses OAuth. 
My personal token is set correctly before this code.  I can create tasks, get projects, get tasks.  I just can't more fields in this query like the API explorer.

Added Code:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/192372431230306/tasks?opt_fields=id,assignee,due_on,name,notes&limit=10&completed_since=now")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

# set up the request
header = {
  "Content-Type" => "application/json"
  }

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path, header)
req.basic_auth(personal_access_token, '')
res = http.start { |http| http.request(req) }
body = JSON.parse(res.body)
puts "projects: #{body['data']}"
```

Comment: Updated to include almost all of the code, if that would help.  Seemed like it should be straight forward.  The result is JSON with task id and name fields only.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't quite enough code here to know what's wrong. It sounds like your code is working to some degree, but maybe there's something different between using a personal token as opposed to OAuth. According to the [Asana API documentation](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/auth#personal-access-token):

> Personal Access Tokens should be used similarly to OAuth access tokens when accessing the API, passing them in the Authorization header:
>
> ```
> curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/me
> ```

So in addition to the URL, you need to use the correct headers. I'm not sure what HTTP library you use, but here's how I would do it with [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty):

```
require 'uri'
require 'httparty'
uri = URI.parse("https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/192372431230306/tasks?opt_fields=id,assignee,due_on,name,notes&limit=10&completed_since=now")

task = HTTParty.get(uri,
                    :headers =>
                    {'Authorization' => "Bearer ${ENV[ACCESS_TOKEN]}"}
                   ).parsed_response
```

If you put your personal access token in the ACCESS_TOKEN environment variable, that should correctly authenticate you for the request.

Still, it seems like there's something else missing if you can get all the fields. Maybe your personal access token is associated with a different account than your OAuth access token? It might help to check the results of [`/users/me/` route](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/users)?